# What's the difference between mnt vs media?

Tags: linux, mount, directory-structure, removable-storage

What is the purpose of having both?  Aren't they both used for mounting drives?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media

Comment: @mohammad.k, this question hadn't been asked before on this site and is totally valid.  See [How should we deal with Google questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8729/307622) on Meta.  I've written more on this subject [here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3702/135943).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I recommend visiting the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard.

- `/media` is **mount point for removable media**. In other words, where system mounts removable media. This directory contains sub-directories used for mounting removable media such as CD-ROMs, floppy disks, etc.
- `/mnt` is **for temporary mounting**. In other words, where user can mount things. This directory is generally used for mounting filessytems temporarily when needed.

Ref:
http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#MEDIAMOUNTPOINT
http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#MNTMOUNTPOINTFORATEMPORARILYMOUNT

Comment: What about less than temporary mounts? Where would you mount a partition "permanently"?

Comment: The only good answer to this is "yes" or "anywhere you like".  You can always locate a mount at a later point with either `mount`, `findmnt`, or other similar commands.

Comment: Why would I mount anything in root? That would require applications and Terminal sudo to be able to write to the. Why not just use home? I'm mounting a folder from local network.

Answer (score 25):

use /mnt for stuff you mount by yourself

leave /media for the system to mount its stuff

Comment: My external hard drives are mounted to /media automatically